# POST php headers failing

Tags: php, javascript, get

When I call a script from Javascript

```
    var user = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var pass = document.getElementById('password').value;
    var conf = document.getElementById('confirm').value;
    var code = document.getElementById('code').value;

    if(code.length == 0 || pass.length == 0 || user.length == 0 || conf.length == 0) {
        alert("Entries empty");
    } else if(pass != conf) {
        alert("Passwords don't match");
    } 

    window.location = "scripts/changepassword.php?Username="+user+"&Password="+pass+"&Code="+code;
```

changepassword.php in my scripts folder has the following headings its refreshing the current page and not passing the parameters into the script. any ideas?

it gives me error2.

scripts/changepassword.php

```
if (isset($_GET['Username']) && isset($_GET['Password'])&& isset($_GET['Code'])) {
...
} else {

    $response = array('result'=>"error2");
    echo json_encode($response);
    echo "hi";
}
```

Comment: That's not a POST request...

Comment: Do you think that it's safe to send password using url parameters (GET method)?

Comment: if you try : window.location = "/scripts/changepassword.php?Username="+user+"&Password="+pass+"&Code="+code;
But still, sending password over GET is not the best solution...

Answer (score 0):

the `window.location` changes the page location (url). If you want to execute the php script without refreshing the page, use [AJAX](http://www.google.sn/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/&ei=ou8TUozCE-PX0QWQ4YCIBQ&usg=AFQjCNFmLRm6sp49xDSldbev20v5BclZ7w)